# Android Studio Rendering error with interactive stuff

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering, android-studio-2.0

i have a problem with android studio rendering things strangely, it only happens with the interactive stuff like buttons. how do i fix this? i do not understand what is happening! it can render buttons but not radio buttons, toolbars, check boxes, sliders etc.. what is going on? it works fine when i install it on a 'real' device (android phone) and on emulators

[image: error with AS]

Comment: Did you try File>Invalidate Caches/Restart?

Comment: Also try changing the view API from 24 to a different version

Comment: changing api helps with EVERYTHING EXCEPT the v7 toolbar thing

Comment: @AbAppletic post as solution and i will give 50 rep

Comment: thanks for that but its still not fully fixed. reinstalling doesnt help either

Comment: Do you want me to post it as a solution?

Comment: I will anyways to help most visitors

Comment: And by the way, next to `colorPrimary` there is a warning sign. What's it say?

Comment: And try changing the device too

Comment: add your build.gradle files. I want to check your configuration ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is changing the display API by clicking [image: This button] and changing the API.

Another solution is to go to **File>Invalidate Caches/Restart**. This usually helps a lot of people.